# linear isoperimetric inequality implies hyperbolicity

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, finitely-generated, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

I am trying to find a nice proof that a finitely presented group satisfying a linear isoperimetric inequality implies it is hyperbolic.

I came across these lecture notes, Theorem 3.22, but I am having a hard time following the proof:

[https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/280-2020/hyplectures_papasoglu.pdf](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ekapovich/280-2020/hyplectures_papasoglu.pdf)

I believe the star function stands for all the closed cells in the van Kampen diagram that touch that subcomplex of the van Kampen diagram.

Why would $l(L_1) \geq l’ - 2\rho$ ? I understand L is a geodesic, but I am unsure why the maximum length of the relators is in this inequality.  I am also unsure why applying this star function $12K$ times gives that sequence, would we not be taking off $2\rho$ each time?

If anyone can make this proof more clear to me or provide different proof that would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a proof in Section 6.5 of the book "Groups, Languages and Automata" by Holt, Rees and Röver. It is nearly four pages long but detailed.

Comment: Did you consider reading a book on geometric group theory? It is standard material, covered in various sources. Papasoglu's notes were taken by his student and were never proofread by Papasoglu himself, so no wonder that you have hard time with some of the arguments.